# Use decimal separator from Regional Settings in CString.Format()

Tags: c++, localization, decimal-point

I try to display my number using the separator from my current regional settings.

Here is my code:

```
Cstring result;    
Cstring myMeasure;  

myMeasure.Format(_T("%.6f %s"), myDouble, myUnit));
result.Format("My volume is: %s", myMeasure);
```

result equals for example "My volume is: 4.565600 mL".
But using french regional settings, the result is still the same (whereas French decimal separator is comma instead of period).

I tried the setlocale() method unsucessfully.

```
char* originalCulture = setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL); // save original culture
setlocale(LC_ALL,"");

Cstring result;    
Cstring myMeasure;  

myMeasure.Format(_T("%.6f %s"), myDouble, myUnit));
result.Format("My volume is: %s", myMeasure);

setlocale(LC_ALL, originalCulture); // restore original culture
```

Can someone help me on that?

Answer (score 0):

You should call `setlocale(LC_ALL, "")` or `setlocale(LC_ALL, "your_locale")` before doing anything else to apply the locale. The former sets the default locale of the operating system, the latter sets a particular locale. Also consider checking [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x99tb11d.aspx) for additional info about `setlocale`.

Comment: I already read this MSDN article but it didn't help about decimal. I need a specific format _T("%.6f %s"). Maybe it is this specific format that imposes the period?